# Get the current and next values for a set of columns (in each group)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sequence

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to construct a new dataframe like this:
For each "id", for each {'A','B','C','D','E','F'} get the current and next values of each of these columns (which appears on next date).

Part of desired results:

[image: results]

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: coud you post what you have tried till now

Comment: Couldn't do much as I don't even know how to start.

Comment: @AnuragReddy: I think this can be done with two nested loops, outer one get the id, inner one get the column and then check if the value != 0, if so add it for example to a list... but this is very slow and not a good approach.

Comment: kindly post data, not pics